# Understanding object construction and assignment

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class DisplayDeck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deck deck = new Deck();
        for (int suit = Card.DIAMONDS; suit <= Card.SPADES; suit++) {
            for (int rank = Card.ACE; rank <= Card.KING; rank++) {
                Card card = deck.getCard(suit, rank);
                System.out.format("%s of %s%n",
                    card.rankToString(card.getRank()),
                    card.suitToString(card.getSuit()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From

```
Deck deck = new Deck();
```

I can understand that it is trying to instantiate the class Deck with the object deck. But when it comes to

```
Card card = deck.getCard(suit, rank);
```

where Card is a class, there's no `new` operator associated with it but it equates to something else, although the LHS seems to be more like instantiating the class Card.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the `Deck` class to see what `deck.getCard(suit,rank)` does. It probably either creates a new `Card` instance (using `new`) or retrieves a reference to an existing `Card` instance stored within the `Deck` instance.

Answer (score 0):

There is `getCard` method in `Deck` class, that accepts *suit* and *rank* arguments(integers), and then somehow with some kind of logic returns instance of `Card` class.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what is confusing you is the concept of **assignment of an object reference**.  See [this link](http://www.c4learn.com/java/java-assigning-object-reference/) for a detailed explanation.

The "LHS" to which you refer (`Card card`) is the left-hand-side of an assignment statement.  The right-hand side is a method call which returns an object reference (and the reference returned by the method is then assigned to the variable `card` on the left side).  The method (`getCard()`) might create the object whose reference it returns, but it looks more like the Card object is probably created by the `Deck()` constructor and probably stored in some kind of Map for lookup.  It would be inefficient to create a new Card object every time `getCard()` is called.

Answer (score -1):

DIAMONDS and such are constants (`public static final int DIAMONDS = 1; // or similar`) which are defined in the Card class. Since they are static, they are there even if there is no instance of Card.